# KeyStore PKCS11 Password callback windows popup

Tags: keystore, signing, pkcs#11, digital

I need to load the user'spassword (or pin) using a native windows popup before loading the KeyStore. This is for a UsbToken based digital signing.
I'm not sure what CallbackHandlar I should use since com.sun.security.auth.callback.DialogCallbackHandler is deprecated.

thanks!